# How to separate string into new lines

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to separate string in this line `"Add Problem Report \n Add Maintenance Report \n Add Expeses Report \n Add Contract"` into new lines. I have tried br, pre and \n but id does not work.

html

```
 <input name="add" value="1" type="checkbox"  /> Add Contents  <a href="#" data-content="Add Problem Report Add Maintenance Report <br> Add Expeses Report <br>Add Contract"
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" id="add_inf">
</span></a>
```

Comment: you might need to escape your string what are you getting instead?

Answer (score 0):

write:

```
<a href = "#"> Add Problem Report Add Maintenance Report <br> Add Expeses Report <br>Add Contract </a>
```

Comment: This will not work at all, the string must be in `data-content= " here"`, I am doing that to display some information mouse-enter event and hide it in mouse-leave event

Answer (score 0):

Use the entity code `&#013;`

```
<a href="#" data-content="Add Problem Report Add Maintenance Report&#013;Add Expeses Report&#013;Add Contract">
```

Comment: it did not separate string into new lines